# JPA - I get multiple rows instead of 1

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I spent many hours to solve my problem but without success. I'd like to achieve something like this (but with ONE row instead of TWO):
[image]

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE odo.d_kryterium_naruszen (
    id                          bigserial primary key,
    kryterium                   text not null,
    data_wpr                    TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
    opr                         bigint not null
);

CREATE TABLE odo.d_czynnik_naruszen (
    id                          bigserial primary key,
    czynnik                     text not null,
    id_kryterium_naruszen       bigint not null references odo.d_kryterium_naruszen(id),
    stopien                     NUMERIC(10,2) not null,
    data_wpr                    TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
    opr                         bigint not null
);

CREATE TABLE odo.d_dotkliwosc_naruszenia (
    id                          bigserial primary key,
    zakres                      numrange not null,
    ocena                       text not null,
    opis                        text not null,
    wymagane_dzialanie          text not null,
    data_wpr                    TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
    opr                         bigint not null
);

CREATE TABLE odo.ocena_naruszenia_wynik (
    id                              bigserial primary key,
    wartosc_dotkliwosci_naruszenia  NUMERIC(10,2) not null,
    status_id                       bigint not null references odo.d_status_oceny_naruszenia(id),
    ocena_naruszenia_id             bigint not null references odo.ocena_naruszenia(id),
    data_wpr                        TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
    opr                             bigint not null
);

create table odo.czynnik_naruszen_wynik(
    id                              bigserial primary key,
    ocena_naruszenia_wynik_id       bigint not null references odo.ocena_naruszenia_wynik(id),
    czynnik_naruszen_id             bigint not null references odo.d_czynnik_naruszen(id),
    komentarz                       text,
    czynnik_wybrany                 boolean not null default false
    wartosc_wybrana                 NUMERIC(10,2) not null,
    data_wpr                        TIMESTAMP not null DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
    opr                             bigint not null
);
```

And here my entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "odo", name = "d_kryterium_naruszen")
public class ViolationCriterion extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "kryterium")
    private String criterion;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_kryterium_naruszen")
    private List<ViolationFactor> violationFactors;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "odo", name = "d_czynnik_naruszen")
public class ViolationFactor extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "czynnik")
    private String factor;

    @Column(name = "stopien")
    private float degree;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "czynnik_naruszen_id")
    private List<IncidentAssessmentFactor> incidentAssessmentFactor;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "odo", name = "czynnik_naruszen_wynik")
public class IncidentAssessmentFactor extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="komentarz")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name="czynnik_wybrany")
    private Boolean factorIsSelected;

    @Column(name = "wartosc_wybrana")
    private Float value;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ocena_naruszenia_wynik_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private IncidentAssessment incidentAssessment;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "odo", name = "ocena_naruszenia_wynik")
public class IncidentAssessment extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="ocena_naruszenia_id")
    private Long incidentAssessmentId;

    @Column(name = "wartosc_dotkliwosci_naruszenia")
    private Float severityDegreeValue;
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ViolationCriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<ViolationCriterion, Long> {

    //  @Query("select vc from ViolationCriterion vc inner join vc.violationFactors vf inner join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf inner join iaf.incidentAssessment ia where ia.incidentAssessmentId = ?1 group by vc ")
    @Query("select vc from ViolationCriterion vc inner join vc.violationFactors vf inner join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf inner join iaf.incidentAssessment ia where ia.incidentAssessmentId = ?1 group by vc ")

    //  @Query(value = "select kn.kryterium from odo.d_kryterium_naruszen kn join odo.d_czynnik_naruszen cn on kn.id = cn.id_kryterium_naruszen join odo.czynnik_naruszen_wynik cnw on cnw.czynnik_naruszen_id = cn.id join odo.ocena_naruszenia_wynik onw on cnw.ocena_naruszenia_wynik_id = onw.id where onw.ocena_naruszenia_id = ?1 group by kn.id, cn.id, cnw.id, onw.id", nativeQuery = true)
//  @Query(value = "select kn.id, kn.kryterium, kn.data_wpr, kn.opr, cn.id, cn.czynnik, cn.stopien, cn.opr, cn.data_wpr, cnw.id, cnw.data_wpr, cnw.opr, cnw.komentarz, cnw.czynnik_wybrany, cnw.wartosc_wybrana, onw.id, onw.data_wpr, onw.opr, onw.ocena_naruszenia_id, onw.wartosc_dotkliwosci_naruszenia from odo.d_kryterium_naruszen kn join odo.d_czynnik_naruszen cn on kn.id = cn.id_kryterium_naruszen join odo.czynnik_naruszen_wynik cnw on cnw.czynnik_naruszen_id = cn.id join odo.ocena_naruszenia_wynik onw on cnw.ocena_naruszenia_wynik_id = onw.id where onw.ocena_naruszenia_id = ?1 group by kn.id, cn.id, cnw.id, onw.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ViolationCriterion> findIncidentAssessmentByIncidentAssessmentId(Long incidentId);
//  List<ViolationCriterion> findByViolationFactorsIncidentAssessmentFactorIncidentAssessmentIncidentAssessmentIdGroupByViolationCriterionCriterion(Long id);
}
```

And here I call my repository:

```
List<ViolationCriterion> violationCriteria = violationCriterionRepository.findIncidentAssessmentByIncidentAssessmentId(id);//vi
```

In a table czynnik_naruszen_wynik I have 2 different rows because I have 2 rows in table ocena_naruszenia_wynik. The problem is that I have multiple values of entity IncidentAssessmentFactor instead of 1

Comment: Use `select distinct vc ...`, and remove the group by clause, which makes no sense. group by is useful when you have an aggregate function in the select clause, like count(), min(), max, avg(), etc. You should also use sets instead of lists for your associations.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misinderstood your question. You get two elements in your list of incidentAssessmentFactor because there are two rows in your database. There is absolutely no reason why the list should only have 1 element. If you have two brothers John and Jack, and I ask "who has a brother named John" (i.e. execute the equivalent of your query), you will be in the result. Then if I hask you "who are your brothers" (i.e. display your list of brothers), you will answer "John and Jack". Not just "John".

Comment: If you only want to select some specific IncidentAssessmentFactor instances, then you should have them in the select clause: `select iaf from ... `

Comment: hmmm so I have to  prepare my DTO object  manually to get back the ViolationCriterion object with all properties...

Comment: I need the fixed structure to send it to the client

Comment: I need the fixed structure to send it to the client... But you're right, that's the wrong way...Impossible in this case probably